# LaTeX Uglifier / obfuscator

Tags: sourcecode, tools, external, xii

For JavaScript you have e.g. [js uglifier](https://www.uglifyjs.net/), which obfuscates the javascript so that it is infeasible for humans to read the javascript code. Also, judging by [@DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)'s [xii.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex) (see below), obfuscations is definitely possible in TeX.

```
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A@@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PAYY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbigskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PAXX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71 72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71 72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jbye
```

Is there any such software that would obfuscate a `.tex`-file, so that it is fairly hard to make sense of?

Possibly related and helpful files:

- [Obfuscating TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/obfuscating-tex)
- [Can I see a plain TeX source file please?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/can-i-see-a-plain-tex-source-file-please)
- [Can you explain how this code works?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/can-you-explain-how-this-code-works)

Comment: Also - please feel free to help out with selecting tags.

Comment: "obfuscate" ! what a thing to say about my lovely code.

Comment: You know anyone interested can just `\tracingall` the code?

Comment: +1 for David's code: it's beautiful, in a fashion. @JosephWright using `\tracingall` will almost always be less efficient than, say, `pdftex`.

Comment: The tricky part with obfucating TeX code is that you need to parse the code before doing some manipulations on it. And parsing TeX code already requires you to implement a full TeX program in the worst case. Also, David's code makes high use of catcode changes which quickly becomes difficult to keep track of to not break code, especially if the program is long. Given that it's hard to implement and there's no real use-case, I doubt that there already are good TeX obfucators.

Comment: @siracusa If I understand the OP correctly he wants to keep the source (for changes), but have a tool that he could call which would do the obfuscation, but you are right that this program would be very complex.

Comment: @TeXnician basically, yes. One _could_ just e.g. switch out all the characters using their respective `^^`-code. Another approach could be to do e.g. rot 13 on all letters that are not used in a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the new `tokcycle` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle), we can map tokens from the input into gibberish and write them to an external file.  Then, in a second document, as long as the mapping is known from the 1st document, we can unmap the externally input gibberish back into LaTeX code:

**MAPPING**

This maps a block of input and writes it to the file `xform.tex`.    Any characters not mapped (e.g., capital letters, numerals, etc.) are presented in the clear.  Obviously, the mapping must be one-to-one, or the unmapping will be ambiguous.

EDITED to avoid using the `\expanded` option of `\addcytoks`, for those users who still have an older LaTeX installation.

After mapping, I also show a detokenized form of the gibberish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newwrite\xfile
\long\def\remaptext#1#2\endremaptext{\tokcycle
  {\addcytoks[4]{\tcremap{##1}}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}{#2}%
  \immediate\openout\xfile=#1
  \immediate\write\xfile{\the\cytoks}
}
\newcommand*\tcmapto[2]{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \tcmapfrom{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*\tcmapfrom[2]{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapfrom#2\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand*\tcremap[1]{\ifcsname tcmapto#1\endcsname
\csname tcmapto#1\expandafter\endcsname\else\expandafter#1\fi}
\tcmapto am \tcmapto bf \tcmapto cz \tcmapto de \tcmapto ey
\tcmapto fl \tcmapto gx \tcmapto hb \tcmapto ic \tcmapto jn
\tcmapto ki \tcmapto lr \tcmapto mh \tcmapto nt \tcmapto ok
\tcmapto ps \tcmapto qa \tcmapto ro \tcmapto sq \tcmapto tw
\tcmapto uj \tcmapto vp \tcmapto wd \tcmapto xg \tcmapto yu
\tcmapto zv \tcmapto ^& \tcmapto &^ \tcmapto +- \tcmapto -+
\begin{document}
\remaptext{xform.tex}%
\section{We can map sectioning, as well}

What can't we \textit{accomplish} if we try?
\begin{equation}
y = f(x) = \frac{1 + x^a}{47b}
\end{equation}
Let us be of good spirit and put our minds to it!
\endremaptext
Encoded input (detokenized):\\
\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An examination of the file `xform.tex` shows the same (line breaks added by me):

```
\section {Wy zmt hms qyzwcktctx, mq dyrr} \par Wbmw zmt'w dy 
\textit {mzzkhsrcqb} cl dy wou? \begin {yajmwckt} u = l(g) = 
\frac {1 - g&m}{47f} \end {yajmwckt} Lyw jq fy kl xkke qscocw 
mte sjw kjo hcteq wk cw!
```

**UNMAPPING**

Now, we run the unmap of the gibberish (contained in the external file `xform.tex`), using the mappings from the original encode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle,etoolbox}
\tokcycleenvironment\unmaptext
  {\addcytoks[4]{\tcunmap{##1}}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
\newcommand*\tcmapto[2]{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \tcmapfrom{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*\tcmapfrom[2]{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapfrom#2\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand*\tcunmap[1]{\ifcsname tcmapfrom#1\endcsname
\csname tcmapfrom#1\expandafter\endcsname\else\expandafter#1\fi}
\tcmapto am \tcmapto bf \tcmapto cz \tcmapto de \tcmapto ey
\tcmapto fl \tcmapto gx \tcmapto hb \tcmapto ic \tcmapto jn
\tcmapto ki \tcmapto lr \tcmapto mh \tcmapto nt \tcmapto ok
\tcmapto ps \tcmapto qa \tcmapto ro \tcmapto sq \tcmapto tw
\tcmapto uj \tcmapto vp \tcmapto wd \tcmapto xg \tcmapto yu
\tcmapto zv \tcmapto ^& \tcmapto &^ \tcmapto +- \tcmapto -+

\newread\infile
\makeatletter
\newcommand\unmapfile[1]{%
\def\fcont{}
\openin\infile=#1
{\endlinechar=-1
 \everyeof{}%
 \loop\unless\ifeof\infile
  \read\infile to \temp
  \ifx\temp\empty\else
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\fcont\expandafter{\temp}%
  \fi
 \repeat
}%
\closein\infile
\expandafter\unmaptext\fcont\endunmaptext
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\unmapfile{xform.tex}
\end{document}
```

which provides the desired output:

[image]

So, if you have possession of the original mapping function and the file containing the mapped text, you can reconstitute the original!

Comment: You made a package just for this?! You are awesome!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman I was actually already working on the package, but this problem fit very well with the package's thrust.  See the examples-documentation at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle for more examples of how it can be used.  It's really a package about helping you build tools that operate on each token of the input stream.