# How can I exclude TeX macros when counting a string's characters in Lua?

Tags: luatex, lua

A follow-up  to my earlier question: [Macro to replace text with random string of same length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632036/macro-to-replace-text-with-random-string-of-same-length?noredirect=1#comment1576247_632036)

Thanks to the answer of @Mico, we now have a macro in Lua to replace a UTF-8 String with random characters.  However, one issue is that when presented with a macro, the code assumes that the characters `\...{` and `}`as well as `\...` are all counted for obfuscation.  This is problematic because for wireframing, it results in random strings longer than in the ordinary text.  Is there a way to get `xyz` and `\textit{xyz}` to have hte same length randomised ASCII output?

The MWE (credit to @Mico) is below:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment and '\luastring' macro
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function rndstring ( inputstring )
  local outputstring, choices, mm, nn
  mm = unicode.utf8.len(inputstring) -- no. of utf8-encoded characters in input string

  -- Place candidate replacement characters in a Lua table:
  choices = { 
     "0","
   }--substantially simplified to reduce size      -- Number of rows in 'choices' table
   nn = #choices 
    
   -- Generate the outputstring in a 'for' loop:
   outputstring = ""
   for i = 1 , mm do
     if unicode.utf8.sub ( inputstring , i , i ) == " "  then
         outputstring = outputstring .. " " -- preserve space char.
     else -- choose a new char randomly from 'choices' table
         outputstring = outputstring .. choices[ math.random ( nn ) ]
     end
   end
 
   return ( outputstring )
end
```

```
\end{luacode}

%% Define a LaTeX macro to invoke the Lua function
\newcommand\rndstring[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(rndstring(\luastring{#1}))}}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\rndstring{This is a string.}
\rnstring{\textit{This is a String}}
%%%% These two Strings should be (but aren't) the same length
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately people have the habit of processing TeX input as regular Lua strings which will always fail when TeX tokens come into play.

What makes this even more sad to see is that LuaTeX actually does already come with a builtin library to process TeX tokens. With this the code not only becomes a lot more compact but it's also absolutely trivial to differentiate between different types of tokens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
local function rndstring()
    local toks = token.scan_toks()

    for n, t in ipairs(toks) do
        if t.cmdname == "letter" then
            -- random number from printable ASCII range
            local r = math.random(33, 126)
            -- create new token with that character and catcode 12
            local letter = token.create(r, 12)
            -- replace old token
            toks[n] = letter
        end
    end

    token.put_next(toks)
end

local lft = lua.get_functions_table()
lft[#lft + 1] = rndstring
token.set_lua("rndstring", #lft, "global")
```

```
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\rndstring{This is a string.}
\rndstring{\textit{This is a String}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Can you explain a little the meaning of `token.put_next(toks)` and `token.set_lua`?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!!!

Comment: @projetmbc This is described in “10.6 The `token` library” in the LuaTeX manual: https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/luatex.pdf#%232338

Comment: Note that `#` on non-sequence tables is undefined in Lua 5.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590885/why-does-luas-length-operator-return-unexpected-values?noredirect=1 (although currently I see lualatex uses Lua 5.3 so no problem there)

Comment: @user202729 It should also be safe to assume that `\luadef` registers will be allocated incrementally, same as `\count`, `\dimen`, `\skip`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think a pure LaTeX solution is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% specify what candidates are in the random replacement
\def\RandomStringASCIIRanges{
  %33-47,
  %48-57,
  58-64,
  65-90,
  91-96,
  97-122,
  %123-126
}

\seq_new:N \l_chrepl_all_repl_seq
\clist_new:N \l_chrepl_tmpa_clist
\int_new:N \l_chrepl_tmpa_int
\tl_new:N \l_chrepl_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \g_chrepl_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \g_chrepl_tmpb_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chrepl_rand_charcode_tl
\tl_new:N \l_chrepl_head_tl

\cs_set:Npn \__chrepl_parse_ascii_range:w |#1-#2| {
  \int_step_inline:nnn {#1} {#2} {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_chrepl_all_repl_seq {##1}
  }
}

\cs_set:Npn \__chrepl_parse_ascii_range:n #1 {
  \__chrepl_parse_ascii_range:w |#1|
}

% parse the ranges
\clist_set:NV \l_chrepl_tmpa_clist \RandomStringASCIIRanges
\clist_map_function:NN \l_chrepl_tmpa_clist \__chrepl_parse_ascii_range:n

% construct an intarray for fast access
\intarray_new:Nn \g_chrepl_repl_intarray {\seq_count:N \l_chrepl_all_repl_seq}
\int_set:Nn \l_chrepl_tmpa_int {1} % loop index
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_chrepl_all_repl_seq {
  \intarray_gset:Nnn \g_chrepl_repl_intarray {\l_chrepl_tmpa_int} {#1}
  \int_incr:N \l_chrepl_tmpa_int
}


\cs_set:Npn \__chrepl_temp_var:n #1 {
  __g_chrepl_temp_#1_tl
}

\cs_set:Npn \__chrepl_group:n #1 {
  \exp_not:n { {#1} }
}

% a recursive replacement algorithm
\cs_set:Npn \chrepl_repl:Nnn #1#2#3 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_if_empty:nF {#2} {
    % check if head is space
    % if head is space, insert it back
    \tl_if_head_is_space:nTF {#2} {
      \tl_gput_right:Nn #1 {\ }
      % recursive call (skip spaces)
      \exp_args:Nnx \chrepl_repl:Nnn #1 {\tl_trim_spaces:n {#2}} {#3}
    } {      
      \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#2} {
        % the results in this group needs to be written to a unique temp variable
        % clear the temp var. corresponding to this level
        \tl_gclear:c {\__chrepl_temp_var:n {#3}}
        \chrepl_repl:cxx {\__chrepl_temp_var:n {#3}} {\tl_head:n {#2}} {\int_eval:n {#3 + 1}}
        \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_chrepl_tmpa_tl {\__chrepl_temp_var:n {#3}}
        \tl_gput_right:Nx #1 {
          \exp_args:NV  \__chrepl_group:n \l_chrepl_tmpa_tl
        }
      } {
        % extract the head
        \tl_set:Nx \l_chrepl_head_tl {\tl_head:n {#2}}
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l_chrepl_head_tl {
          % if head is control sequence, insert it back
          \exp_args:NV \token_if_cs:NTF \l_chrepl_head_tl {
            \tl_show:N \l_chrepl_head_tl
            \tl_gput_right:NV #1 \l_chrepl_head_tl
          } {
            % otherwise, do replacement
            % randomly pick a charcode from the intarray
            \tl_set:Nx \l_chrepl_rand_charcode_tl {\intarray_rand_item:N \g_chrepl_repl_intarray}
            % generate the corresponding character
            \tl_gput_right:Nx #1 {\char_generate:nn {\l_chrepl_rand_charcode_tl} {12}}
          }
        }
      }
      % recursive call
      \exp_args:Nnx \chrepl_repl:Nnn #1 {\tl_tail:n {#2}} {#3}
    }
  }
  \group_end:
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chrepl_repl:Nnn {cxx}

% user function
\newcommand{\rndstr}[1]{
  \tl_gclear:N \g_chrepl_tmpa_tl % used to store results
  \chrepl_repl:Nnn \g_chrepl_tmpa_tl {#1} {1}
  \tl_show:N \g_chrepl_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \g_chrepl_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\texttt{\rndstr{Hello World}}

\texttt{\rndstr{Hello Владимир öäüß}}

\texttt{\rndstr{this \textsl{ab{\huge\bfseries cdef}gh}} nested groups.}

\texttt{\rndstr{this {ab{cdef}gh}} nested groups.}

\texttt{\rndstr{this abcdefgh nested groups.}}

\texttt{\rndstr{this \{abcdefgh\} nested groups.}}

\texttt{\rndstr{Once upon a time, there was ...}}

\end{document}
```