# How can I avoid TeX environment's when token filtering in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, lua

This is a follow-up to: [How can I exclude TeX macros when counting a string's characters in Lua?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632408/how-can-i-exclude-tex-macros-when-counting-a-strings-characters-in-lua/632464#632464)

Thanks to @Henri Menke's excellent answer to that question (below), I know how to filter out macros like `\textit{abc}` with Lua.  However, this approach below seems to break down with environments like `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local function rndstring()
    local toks = token.scan_toks()

for n, t in ipairs(toks) do
    if t.cmdname == "letter" then
        -- random number from printable ASCII range
        local r = math.random(33, 126)
        -- create new token with that character and catcode 12
        local letter = token.create(r, 12)
        -- replace old token
        toks[n] = letter
    end
end

token.put_next(toks)
end

local lft = lua.get_functions_table()
lft[#lft + 1] = rndstring
token.set_lua("rndstring", #lft, "global")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\rndstring{This string works.}

\rndstring{\textit{This string works}}

\rndstring{\begin{quote}This String Does not work\end{quote}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This sets a boolean flag and only changes letters while it is true. if `\begin` or `\end` is seen the flag is set false until a `}` is seen so the environment name is not mangled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local function rndstring()
    local toks = token.scan_toks()
    local on = true
for n, t in ipairs(toks) do
    if t.csname == "begin" or t.csname == "end" then
       on = false
    end
   if not(on) and t.cmdname == "right_brace" then
     on = true
   end
    if on and t.cmdname == "letter" then
        -- random number from printable ASCII range
        local r = math.random(33, 126)
        -- create new token with that character and catcode 12
        local letter = token.create(r, 12)
        -- replace old token
        toks[n] = letter
    end
end

token.put_next(toks)
end

local lft = lua.get_functions_table()
lft[#lft + 1] = rndstring
token.set_lua("rndstring", #lft, "global")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\rndstring{This string works.}

\rndstring{\textit{This string works}}

\rndstring{\begin{quote}This String Does not work\end{quote}}

\end{document}
```